# VueJS form dont submit from Phone but works in browser

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mobile, submit

I have seen this type of question asked before, but I have not been able to find an appropriate answer.

I have a VueJS application where a submit function works fine from a browser (Chrome, Firefox etc.) but does NOT submit from a phone (tested with Safari).

My submit method from within the component looks like this:

```
methods: {
     async removeBet(item) {
      this.bet.id = item
      try {
        await this.$http.post("/user/deletePendingBet", this.bet);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
    },
    }
```

I call the method like this:

```
<a class="dropdown-item" @click="removeBet(value._id)" href="/newBet">Delete</a>
```

I assume the DB query is not needed, as this is properly something with the way the method is called.

I don't have big experience with mobile development, so my question would be is Safari only accept forms submitted in a certain way? And in that case, what would be the right way to submit the form using JS frameworks like Vue in this case?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you are using anchor tag, which is not a good practice.

As you are not preventing the browser to call your `@click`, so due to this it will not call `@click`, because browser will persist it's default behavior, and call `href`.

I will suggest to change it to `<div>` or `<span>`, but may be it's a requirement to use `<a>`, so to fix this, first of all remove `href` and then use `@click.prevent="remove..."` to make it working. It will prevent the default behavior of `<a>` and will call `@click`.

Notice `.prevent` after `@click`. You can read more [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers).

Comment: Thank you! I will try that out. Just funny, how chrome and firefox don't "complain" about this, but only safari from phone. It works fine from desktop.